# Bathroom Vanity Without Baseboard Behind It

Tags: bathroom, sink, appliances, baseboard, vanity

I'm trying to figure out what is in normal spectrum of work for baseboards underneath/behind a bathroom vanity. Our contractor used baseboards around the side of the vanity, but left it off the wall underneath and around the back and side of the vanity. Hopefully the below picture gives you an idea. It shows the baseboard terminating at the vanity leg. On the wall to the side of the vanity, there is a gap where the wall does not meet the floor. On the wall behind the vanity, there is no visible gap, but there is an unfinished strip where the wall was taped off during painting, maybe.

[image]

So my questions are, how normal is this approach to a vanity? Are there any code issues with this? And what realistically could we do to make this look a bit more finished? (The contractor proposes to close the gap with spray foam. Is that approach ok?)

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Is that an air register (supply or return) there? I see what looks like sheet metal. Still a lousy job.

Comment: I don’t think so, I believe it is just a gap. I think the previous vanity went to the floor and would have covered that section of wall, so I guess a gap would have been less of an issue then.

Comment: Leaving the area under the vanity exposed like that was the big mistake. Close it off with a matching board, or a grill.

Comment: @kreemoweet - Are you suggesting boarding it at the front or the back of the vanity? My sense is that a board might work at the back but wouldn’t make sense at the front, since it has legs that don’t totally reach ground and would not match the free standing vanity style. Also the gap would still be somewhat visible from the side.

Comment: I am still wondering why the leg is floating in mid air

Comment: @Yorik - That is a bit of an illusion. There are leg tips. One is visible on the back leg but the one on the front is obscured by the angle.

Answer (score 2):

To be blunt, that looks like an inexperienced Hack did the job.

The wall should have been finished as if nothing would be in front of it. That meaning fully painted and with baseboards.

If the baseboards needed to be notched for the legs of the vanity, so be it. It is what a good tradesman with pride in his work would do.

Comment: I don't know about that—notching out the marble base panel could preclude vanity changes in the future (but I guess replacing them could be a problem for the future contractor).

Comment: @RMDman - Thanks for the answer. Any thoughts on what reasonably could be done at this stage to make it look more finished?

Comment: Base board or skirting board ( in England) should be installed to close the gap between the floor and wall.  I know it won't be easy, but that is the result of not doing the job properly at the begining.

Comment: @Huesmann, I'm not sure that is marble, or just a poor paint job on a wood baseboard.

Comment: @RMDman you could be right, but it doesn't look like wood to me.  Actually, kinda looks like cove tile.

Comment: Under the vanity, it is a paint job that terminates at around the level that would be covered by baseboard, if it had been installed. Instead, you can see a strip of white, which I think is primer, and a strip of green, which I think is the old paint color. There is only marble base plate on the portion of the wall that is not under the vanity.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that there's no baseboard to the left of the leg. I'd ask the contractor to install that where it's visible.

For the part that's under the vanity, I really wouldn't worry about it. Honestly, how often are you laying on the floor of the bathroom looking under there? Are you concerned that any future mice might not think highly of you for having an otherwise invisible bit unfinished?

My bigger concern would be that the front left leg appears to be floating. It needs a shim, or more appropriately for this kind of cabinet, a leg adjuster that would screw into the bottom of the leg then extend to touch the ground. Unless this has been screwed to the wall behind, I'm surprised it doesn't wobble.

Comment: The legs have tips on them, which mostly is why it appears to be floating. You can see a black tip in the picture on the back leg. The front leg is similar. The vanity is screwed to the wall I believe.

Comment: Good to know, @ISOAnswers. I did look for a leg there, I just couldn't see it.